# YAML by example

Tags: yaml

I am trying to design the configuration file format for my app and have chosen YAML. However, this (obviously) means I need to be able to define, parse and validate proper YAML syntax!

In the config file, there must be a collection/sequence called `widgets`. This sequence needs to contain a set of typed widgets (possible types are `fizz`, `buzz` and `foobaz`). Each widget also has a `name` and various other properties (depending on the type). For example:

```
myappconfig.yaml
================
widgets:
  - buzz:
      name: Red Buzz
      isSilly: true
  - buzz:
      name: Blue Buzz
      isSilly: false
  - foobaz:
      name: Abracadabra
      rating: 3000
      specialty: Such YAML much amaze
```

My simple question is: Have I created a proper/valid YAML file above? Meaning, based on my constraints, am I understanding YAML syntax correctly in my implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the syntax of your YAML, e.g. [on this website](http://www.yamllint.com/).

Your YAML is parsed as this:

```
{'widgets': [{'buzz': {'name': 'Red Buzz', 'isSilly': True}}, {'buzz': {'name': 'Blue Buzz', 'isSilly': False}}, {'foobaz': {'rating': 3000, 'name': 'Abracadabra', 'specialty': 'Such YAML much amaze'}}]}
```

which looks like what you seem to be after.

Answer (score 1):

If the widget name should be unique, you can use it for keys:

```
widgets:
  RedBuzz:
    type: buzz
    isSilly: true
  BlueBuzz:
    type: buzz
    isSilly: false
  Abracadabra:
    type: foobaz
    rating: 3000
    specialty: Such YAML much amaze
```

This one uses grouping by widget type:

```
widgets:
  buzz:
    - RedBuzz:
        isSilly: true
    - Blue Buzz:
        isSilly: false

  foobaz:
    - Abracadabra:
        rating: 3000
        specialty: Such YAML much amaze
```

Also if you're feeling nerdy you can use widgets types merge like this:

```
buzz_widget: &buzz_widget
  type: buzz

foobaz_widget: &foobaz_widget
  type: foobaz

widgets:
  RedBuzz:
      isSilly: true
      <<: *buzz_widget
  BlueBuzz:
      isSilly: false
      <<: *buzz_widget
  Abracadabra:
      rating: 3000
      specialty: Such YAML much amaze
      <<: *foobaz_widget
```

---

As for me, using nested key-values structure (for non-primitive elements) is preferable. Being parsed into a map, you can always access it's values as a collection. At the same time you have unique constraint and constant access time (by key). If your keys should not be unique, then you should try restructuring it before giving back to sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure your second example does what you intend. The third and fourth lines, for example, describe a mapping with two keys: `RedBuzz` whose value is `null`, and `isSilly`, whose value is `true`. I think you perhaps intended for `isSilly` to be indented more than `RedBuzz` so that lines three and four would describe a mapping with one key, `RedBuzz`, whose value is a mapping with one key, `isSilly`. Perhaps I'm mistaken about your intent, though.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right, I'm missing intents! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, not all text editors and IDEs validate YAML.

[Difff.app](https://difff.app/formatter/yaml) validates, formats, and converts YAML or other text files. There is an article about YAML basics with examples.